# Test Plans - looking for instances of an individual Test

Tags: testcase, manual-testing

I'm new to Test Plans and new to a particular project.  I have a Test Cases linked to a work tickets.  But how do I find out which Test Plans an individual Test case has been put into?  I need to see how often it's been run and what it's executions status is. The project has hundreds of Test Plans and I'd rather not open them all to try and find one Test Case.

Answer (score 0):

It usually depends on the Test Case management software we use. We usually add a feature tag to link individual test cases to a test plan and than we can take a list of the execution report w.r.t releases. Usually as a software testing company, we use sifferent set of test case management tools. Please list us the Test case management tool you use to clarify the doubts.

Comment: I've used several but in this instance have been forced into using TestPlans in Azure Devops